# I have a problrm with if statement and while loop and dictionary in python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement, while-loop

```
men = {1111111111: 'Amal', 2222222222: 'Mohammed', 3333333333: 'Khadijah', 4444444444: 'Abdullah', 5555555555: 'Rawan',
       6666666666: 'Faisal', 7777777777: 'Layla'}


def mo():
    r = int(input('Please Enter The Number: '))
    if r in men:
        print(men[r])
    elif r not in men:
        print('Sorry, the number is not found')
    elif r >= 11:
        while r >= 11:
            r = r + 1 == 1
            print('This is invalid number')
mo()
```

I have problem in the `elif`. What I want is if I write more than 10 characters in the console, then the code will print `'This is invalid number'`. But instead the code prints `'Sorry, the number is not found'`.

Output:

```
Please Enter The Number: 111111111111111
Sorry, the number is not found

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted by **ksohan** is correct, but there's a catch. What you want is if the number entered is greater than 10 characters, then console will print 'This is invalid number'. If you want to compare the length of characters then you should first typecast  `r`  variable to string and then compare its length with 10.

Try this:

```
men = {1111111111: 'Amal', 2222222222: 'Mohammed', 3333333333: 'Khadijah', 4444444444: 'Abdullah', 5555555555: 'Rawan',
       6666666666: 'Faisal', 7777777777: 'Layla'}


def mo():
    r = int(input('Please Enter The Number: '))
    if r in men:
        print(men[r])
    elif len(str(r)) > 10:
        print('This is invalid number')
    elif r not in men:
        print('Sorry, the number is not found')
mo()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Divyanshu. Somehow I missed that. I have corrected it

Comment: @ksohan You're welcome :-)

Comment: Thanks, @DivyanshuTiwari

Comment: Always welcome, @EhH5y

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you using `while` loop and `r = r + 1 == 1` in your code. But I guess you want something like this:

```
men = {1111111111: 'Amal', 2222222222: 'Mohammed', 3333333333: 'Khadijah', 4444444444: 'Abdullah', 5555555555: 'Rawan',
       6666666666: 'Faisal', 7777777777: 'Layla'}


def mo():
    r = int(input('Please Enter The Number: '))
    if r in men:
        print(men[r])
    elif len(str(r)) >= 11:
        print('This is invalid number')
    elif r not in men:
        print('Sorry, the number is not found')
mo()
```

Comment: I tried your code but the same problem have shownup but in different way this time the console print 'This is invalid number' even if i have write less than 10 characters

Comment: I have modified the code. Please use the updated code @EhH5y

Answer (score 0):

if / elif / else

runs until the first condition is met.
in your case, the first condition met is `r not in men`

```py
if(condition):
  do something
elif(condition):
  do something else
elif(condition):
  do something else
else:
  do something
```

You could re-order them, so that the length check happens before checking if it's in the dict.